# ANTLR4 grammar parser issue

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am relatively new to ANTLR so bear with me pls.

I have the following imitation of a grammar for parsing very simple first-order logic formulas:

```
grammar graph;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* PARSER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input
: 
TRUE | FALSE | formula | EOF
;

formula
: 
(element)+ ST condition
;

element 
:
quantifier IN domain
;

condition
:
atom EQUALS (assignment | atom)
;

atom
:
variable DOT property
;

quantifier 
:
(FOREACH | EXISTS) variable
;

domain
:
(GRAPH_A | GRAPH_B)
;

variable
:   
(NODE | EDGE)
;

property
:
(COLOR | VALUE)
;

assignment
:
(COLORTYPE | NUMBER)
;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* LEXER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
COLORTYPE : ('a'..'z')+ ;

NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+ (DOT ('0'..'9')+)? ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

EXISTS  : 'Exists' ;

FOREACH : 'Foreach' ;

TRUE : 'True' ;

FALSE : 'False' ;

ST : '->' ; 

NODE : 'node' ;

EDGE : 'edge' ;

IN : 'in' ;

GRAPH_A : 'GraphA' ;

GRAPH_B : 'GraphB' ;

COLOR : 'color' ;

VALUE : 'value' ;

EQUALS : '=' ;

DOT : '.' ;
```

The grammar is pretty straightforward. I was able to generate the lexer and parser classes with

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool graph.g4
```

but when I try to parse the following expression

```
Exists node in GraphA -> node.color = 'red'
```

I end up with the following error:

line 1:38 token recognition error at: '''

line 1:42 token recognition error at: '''

No method for rule r or it has arguments

What is the meaning of rule 'r'? How can I understand where the problem is coming for? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Note the errors point to `'''`, i.e. a single quote in your input.  You have nothing in your lexer/parser rules to handle a quoted string, i.e. `'red'`.  This would be an answer except I don't know enough about ANTLR4 to tell you how to solve the problem.  You could change the input to `Exists node in GraphA -> node.color = red` without the quotes around "red" and that should parse OK.

Comment: well i have COLORTYPE : ('a'..'z')+ ; which should be able to parse 'red'

Comment: Not true.  It will parse `red` but not `'red'`.  The quotes in the rule are ANTLR metacharacters.

Comment: well if I try `=red` then I end up only with `No method for rule r or it has arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `COLORTYPE` matches the input `red`, but you actually specified `'red'`. You need to do one of the following:

1. Remove the quotes around `red` in your input.
2. Add quotes to your `COLORTYPE` rule:

   ```
   COLORTYPE : '\'' [a-z]+ '\'';
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Move COLORTYPE last; it also matches the keywords. ANTLR resolves ambiguities to the rule mentioned first.

Comment: well, you need to move it but you also need to realize you are not matching a single quote anywhere. Probably will want this no? See Sam's entry.

Answer (score 1):

When I make the following changes to your grammar, it works for me:

1. Move COLORTYPE to the end, since as others have mentioned, it matches before your keywords.
2. Change your 'condition' rule to:

   atom EQUALS QUOTE? (assignment | atom) QUOTE?
3. Add this at the end:

   QUOTE : '\'' ;

Answer (score 0):

i am a bit late i think, but

> "No method for rule r or it has arguments"

this is produced because you are calling something like this

```
C:\>grun graph r -gui
```

you should instead use

```
C:\>grun graph input -gui
```